# Initialize firebase management with Service Account Credential without files- System.NotSupportedException - "Tag '27' not supported."

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, service-accounts, google-iam

```
 public static  class ServiceAccountManager
 {
 public static ServiceAccountKey Datakey { get; private set; }

 public static void CreateKey(string serviceAccountEmail)
    {            
        Datakey = Service.Projects.ServiceAccounts.Keys.Create(
            new CreateServiceAccountKeyRequest(),
            "projects/-/serviceAccounts/" + serviceAccountEmail)
            .Execute();
        Console.WriteLine("Created key: " + Datakey.Name);
    }
 .......
 }
```

Initialize with PrivateKey

```
   private static void InitializeFirebaseManagement()
    {
       
        var servicecredential = new ServiceAccountCredential(new 
   ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(CloudManager.ProjectId)
            .FromPrivateKey("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- 
   "+ServiceAccountManager.Datakey.PrivateKeyData+"-----END PRIVATE KEY-----")
        );
        var credential =GoogleCredential.FromServiceAccountCredential(servicecredential);
   if (CloudManager.Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired)
        {
            credential =CloudManager.Credential.CreateScoped(FirebaseManagementService.Scope.CloudPlatform);
        _firebaseManagementService = new FirebaseManagementService(
           new BaseClientService.Initializer()
           {
               
               HttpClientInitializer = credential,
               ApplicationName = CloudManager.ApplicationName

           });         
        }
    }
```

### Problem

Doesn't work  extracting the Key from the given PKCS8 private key(method FromPrivateKey())

---

### Output

- Value ServiceAccountManager.Datakey.PrivateKeyData =

ewogICJ0eXBlIjogInNlcnZpY2VfYWNjb3VudCIsCiAgInByb2plY3RfaWQiOiAiZ2FtYW5ldC0yOSIsCiAgInByaXZhdGVfa2V5X2lkIjogImEyOGNjNzA4ZWFhNjFlZTBmNGQ0NWQ2NTRjZOXd2ZEM1VS9XNGlST3FSQXJmVFk3TzhcbjFQZEdhWVU3UHhJTjlsemhXTFJTR0xyWVp3MmtjeS95OG1TYVFUQUx1K3lzcjJVWVJGVjNJd1k1MmM1anVIQzBcbmNNTUxFSX...................GhfcHJvdmlkZXJfeDUwOV9jZXJ0X3VybCI6ICJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9vYXV0aDIvdjEvY2VydHMiLAogICJjbGllbnRfeDUwOV9jZXJ0X3VybCI6ICJodHRwczovL3d3dy5nb29nbGVhcGlzLmNvbS9yb2JvdC92MS9tZXRhZGF0YS94NTA5L2dhbWFuZXRjb20lNDBnYW1hbmV0LTI5LmlhbS5nc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQuY29tIgp9Cg==

---

### Exception

- System.NotSupportedException: "Tag '27' not supported."

  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8.Asn1.Decoder.Decode()
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8.Asn1.Decode(Byte[] bs)
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Pkcs8.DecodeRsaParameters(String pkcs8PrivateKey)
  at
  Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer.FromPrivateKey(String
  privateKey)
  at CloudResourceManagers.Program.InitializeFirebaseManagement()
  in
  /Users/mac/Desktop/TestApp/CloudResourceManager/Program.cs:line 84
  at CloudResourceManagers.Program.Main(String[] args)
  in
  /Users/mac/Desktop/TestApp/CloudResourceManager/Program.cs:55

Comment: Please pay close attention when you select tags, don't just write a single letter and press Enter. Then you will most certainly select the wrong tags, like the C language tag instead of C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java code:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(key.decodePrivateKeyData());
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(stream);
```

C#:

```
var buffer = Convert.FromBase64String(ServiceAccountManager.DataKey.PrivateKeyData);
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(stream);
```